# Notation for $y$-restriction?

Tags: notation

$f(x) \; \{a<x<b\}$ can be written $[f(x)]^b_a$. Is there an equivalent notation for $f(x) \; \{a<y<b\}$?

*Edited to add:* for instance,

[image]

Comment: I had never seen this notation. What does its mean?

Comment: @Azif00 I may have messed it up. The bits in curly braces are meant to read "for $x$ between $a$ and b" and "for $y$ between $a$ and $b$".

Comment: Also refer to this set $\{ f(x) :\, a<x<b \}$?

Comment: @Azif00 Looks right, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I understand the notation $[f(x)]_{a}^{b}$ to mean $f(b) - f(a)$ (e.g. when evaluating a definite integral with $a$ and $b$ being the lower and upper limits of integration, respectively).  The set of values of $f(x)$ with $a < x < b$ is usually denoted by $f((a,b))$, i.e. the *image of the interval $(a,b)$ under $f$*.  I am not sure what you mean by $f(x)\ \{a < y < b\}$.  What is $y$?  Where did it come from?  Do you mean the set $a < f(x) < b$?  Why not write $f(X) \cap (a,b)$ (where $X$ is the domain of $f$?  Or are you interested in $f^{-1}((a,b))$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson See image added to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't, but you could probably make it clear with $[f(x)]_{y \geq a}^{y \leq b}$